# jQuery ajax request html page

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to use jquery client side to load linkedin profile page using this code :

```
 $.get( "https://dz.linkedin.com/pub/arezki-lebdiri/75/a51/4b5", function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

and i get this error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://dz.linkedin.com/pub/arezki-lebdiri/75/a51/4b5. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

so any help please to change  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the browsr

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" must be present on the page you are requesting. Since requested page is on LinkedIn, you cannot change Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Perhaps, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866912/load-linkedin-member-profile-by-inserting-javascript-with-jquery) can help you

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: You should use an iframe to display page profil BUT linkedin has disallowed it. Then you could still proxify it server side but that would be again linkedin TOS. The only viable solution is to use their API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing an "origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error)

Answer (score 1):

just use this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)
to allow to you request any site with ajax from any source